# BeautifulSoup - Saving scraped data in to rows and columns

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've just started to get into web scraping using Python and I'm slowly making progress. I hope someone can help me out.

I'm trying to scrape all the aircraft on Icelandic aircraft register. I've written a script that pulls all the data in from the table a prints it to the screen as shown here:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = "https://www.icetra.is/aviation/aircraft/register/"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

aircraft = soup.findAll('tr')

for ac in aircraft:
    print(ac.get_text())
```

What i would like to be able to do is save it to a csv file with rows and columns, my guess would be that i need to have each of the columns as a variable and read each row of data into the relevant column.

Regards,
Mark

Comment: Try [`pandas.from_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-read-html) before rolling your own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.to_csv()` from `pandas`. Here's an example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = "https://www.icetra.is/aviation/aircraft/register/"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

aircraft = soup.findAll('tr')

aircrafts = [ac.get_text() for ac in aircraft]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Aircrafts": aircrafts})
df.to_csv("aircrafts.csv")
```

**Edit:** I've noticed that `soup.findAll('tr')` might be getting more information that you wanted, in this case its getting the text from the whole row. You might want to use `ac.stripped_strings` ([documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings)) to get each string from the column.

**Edit 2:** You should try `pd.read_html()` to read this table. However, I tried fixing my last code and got this solution:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = "https://www.icetra.is/aviation/aircraft/register/"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

aircraft = soup.findAll('tr')
rows = [list(ac.stripped_strings) for ac in aircraft]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows)
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df.drop(index=0, inplace=True)
df.to_csv("aircrafts.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Hi Leo,

Thank you so much, edit 2 of your solution was exactly what i was after!